# JQuery - do this if element with specific ID (wildecard) has been clicked on

Tags: javascript, jquery

I try to join few function with similar functionality into one. I would like to separate this function depending which button is clicked on.

```
 $(document).on('click', '[id^=pack-payreq-toggle-], [id^=test-payreq-toggle-]', function(e) {
      e.preventDefault();

      if($("[id^='pack-payreq-toggle-]").length > 0) { console.log('Pack Pay Req'); }
      if($("[id^='test-payreq-toggle-]").length > 0) { console.log('Test Pay Req'); }
});
```

I can manage my result with `"has class"`, but I would like to learn how to recognize which element is pressed based on id name. Thank you for your advice in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `$(this).attr('id')` inside the click function so that you can check the part of that value to contain `pack` or `test` string in the `id` using something like:

```
var idVal = $(this).attr('id');
if(idVal.indexOf('pack') !== -1){
  console.log('Pack Pay Req'); 
}
if(idVal.indexOf('test') !== -1){
  console.log('Test Pay Req'); 
}
```

This is because if the value `test` or `pack` exist in the string then it will have index from `0` to `idVal.length-1`. So, we can know that value exist in the `id` by checking the index not equal (or greater than) `-1`

Comment: thank you. you put me on the right track.... i had to do an adjustment ... if(idVal.indexOf('pack') > -1) and if(idVal.indexOf('test') > -1) otherwise didn't work

Comment: i would be glad if someone could explain why?

Comment: Actually that should be `-1`, like, `idVal.indexOf('pack') !== -1` .  @Nita updated the answer with reason

Comment: @Nita you can tick mark the answer if it was helpful to you

Comment: I have not seen your update. Sorry, Thanks for your help. Nice one,

Comment: FYI, `$(this).attr('id')` can be simplified to just `this.id`.